# Question on MySQL Partitioning

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, partitioning

Using version 5.5 (on which I'm stuck), I have a table I want to partition, here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `emp` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gen_year` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (year(from_unixtime(`date1`))) VIRTUAL,
  `gen_month` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (month(from_unixtime(`date1`))) VIRTUAL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`gen_year`,`gen_month`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY HASH (12*gen_year+gen_month) PARTITIONS 77 ;
```

As you can see I want to partition by unique month (taking the year into account). I set 77 partitions because the test data I have put in there uniformly cover 77 months.

When I run the 1<sup>st</sup> query below, I get pruning just fine, only one partition gets queried.
When I run the 2<sup>nd</sup> query, I'd expect just a few partitions to be queried, but instead ALL are.

1. `select count(*) from emp where gen_year=1984 and month=8;`
2. `select count(*) from emp where gen_year=1984 and month>8;`
3. `select count(*) from emp where gen_year=1984 and month BETWEEN 8 AND 12;`

`EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` gives one partition for the first query, but all 77 partitions for the others.

Please advise on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* range (eg `month>8` or `month BETWEEN 8 AND 12`) leads to punting on partition pruning, hence 77 partitions are selected.  That is, `PARTITION BY HASH` is useless for ranges.  Meanwhile, non-partitioning is excellent for the other type of queries -- "point queries".  So don't bother using `BY HASH`!

Where does `id` come from?  Typically it is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but apparently not for your table.

```
select count(*) from emp where gen_year=1984 and month=8;
```

can be significantly sped up by

- Storing `date1` as either a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`.  With fractional seconds if needed.
- Adding `INDEX(date1)`
- Writing the query thus:

  `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMP
       WHERE date1 >= '1984-08-01'
         AND date1  < '1984-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH`

If you build and maintain a Summary table, then the query becomes 'instantaneous', and even the other query will be faster than

```
     WHERE date1 >= '1984-09-01'
       AND date1  < '1985-01-01'
```

InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Promote the `UNIQUE` key to primary.  (Though I have serious doubts about that index.)

These are all "range" tests:  `BETWEEN`, `>=`, `<`.  All may work well with non-partitioned tables, but fail miserably on `PARTITION BY HASH` tables (when the range involves the partition-key).

Answer (score 0):

How does the database know that gen_month=13 is not a valid value and that it shouldn't search in the partition for that value?

How does the database know that gen_month=77+8 is not a valid value?

Logically, `gen_months > 8` implies "search all partitions".

Try `gen_months between 9 and 12` to see if that uses the correct number of partitions.

Comment: Those work with `PARTITION BY RANGE`.  `BY HASH` does not optimize any flavor of 'range' on the partition-key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I forgot to mention that I tried the "between 8 and 12" trick and got, again, all 77 partitions. So, the "=" operator works fine, but the ">" and the "between" fail to prune.

Comment: Edit your own question and put in any extra information there! Comments are for pointing people to clarifications (using @ + handle - for me @V)érace and requests for extra information from potential responders. Please delete this and put the information in your question.

Comment: @Vérace - (I added it in case George does not have the reputation to edit.)

Comment: He always has enough reputation to edit his own question - and (just for completeness), he (or any user of whatever rep) can always propose edits - it's just that they are subject to approval!